# Flex UI Component for graphical Disk Space Usage status indicator

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder

I am creating a plugin for VMWare vSphere Web Client using Flex 4.6.

I am trying to create a disk usage status indicator which looks something like this:

[image: Disk Usage status indicator]

I tried using ProgressBar Control (As the usage status will be shaded only after the page is loaded) and then got struck there itself.

```
<mx:ProgressBar id="storageStatusBar" width="300" height="18" 
    label="USED %1 Gb" indeterminate="false" labelPlacement="bottom"
    mode="polled" initialize="storageStatusBar_initializeHandler()"/>
```

Initializer Function:

```
private function storageStatusBar_initializeHandler():void
{
    storageStatusBar.setProgress(100,200);
}
```

I realized that this a bad idea because I didn't and I don't know what should I set for source attribute of progressbar.

I am new to flex, so it'll be great if someone can guide me on which component control is best suitable for creating this UI.

Comment: Are you asking how to read disk usage information, or do you just need to set the ProgressBar mode to "manual"?

Comment: ProgressBar seems like an appropriate component for your needs. As drkstr1 says, set mode="manual" and call setProgress whenever you require it.

Comment: @drkstr1 I have the disk usage info. I just need to set the values. Thank you drkstr1 & Lee Burrows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the ProgressBar mode to "manual", and you can control the values through Actionscript, no source needed.